# Add LinearLayout Dynamically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, orientation, viewgroup

I am using `LinearLayout` which has to be inserted dynamically so the problem with this is :

if My Main `Linearlayout` is`Lmain` - vertical orientation   and `Lh` - horrizontal orientation inside Lmain added .

`v1,v2` view is added to Lh then format visible will be

`Lh` holds - `v1,v2`

if i add new `v3` then `v1,v2,v3` now i am not considering any other layout than `LinearLayout` . If i add v3 view inside Lh should be : `v3,v1,v2` or `v1,v3,v2`  .

I just want to maintain basics of LinearLayout but also i just want to know how i can add views position according to my insertion beginning , middle or end .

Is it possible to do this and also if its possible , do please let me know .

I can insert view at position using `addView(view,position)` but i am using touchlistner over views.

If i am pointing over the top or left or bottom or center or end of the layout , how would i detect to insert view at right position with maintaining same orientation?

Comment: Its possibly just me but, your question isn't quite explicit. Can you clarify?

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @Shaishav sorry!  sure , please ask me what you didn't get it  in this question so i will write it down again .

Comment: @Shaishav please check again.

Comment: It appears you want to add your views to a specific position. If thats the case, you can try `Lh.addView(view, position)`.

Comment: @Shaishav If i am pointing on top or left or right or bottom of the linearlayout how i would identify to insert the view at the right position ??